# PHP urldecode() function wont work for email validation

Tags: php, urldecode

Im trying to decode the email, since its been encoded in the url, but the `urldecode()` function wont decode it.

I'v also tried `rawurldecode()`, then tried first encoding it myself and then decoding it, but its still encoded like %40 instead of an @ sign.

Here is the code:

```
$isValid = ! User::emailExists(urldecode($_GET['email']));
```

Im getting something like this:

http://localhost/account/validate-email?email=some_email%40gmail.com

Comment: `var_dump(urldecode($_GET['email']))`. What do you get? If the value is actually like your example, the url decode works fine see https://3v4l.org/Z94pA

Comment: i am keep getting: some_email%40gmail.com

Comment: Please provide the output from the above.

Comment: A `$_GET` is already decoded. Maybe you are triple encoding prior to the transmission? What does `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` give?

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple test:

```
<?php
$email = "some_email%40example.com";
var_dump($email);
var_dump(urldecode($email));
var_dump(rawurldecode($email));
```

The (expected) output is:

> string(24) "some_email%40example.com"
>
> string(22) "some_email@example.com"
>
> string(22) "some_email@example.com"

So decoding works as expected.

Could it be that you are looking at a single example where what you think is a `%40` actually is something else, like a sequence that contains a unicode character that only *looks like* those you expect but actually is different?

Answer (score 0):

$_GET gets automatically decoded, are sure you're correctly encoding the url in the first place?

Also remember that you should pay attention also to the encoding of the url for the HTML attribute you put it into:

It might be you're double encoding and/or wrongly encoding!

Comment: My $_GET for some reason gets automatically encoded, so i need to decode it, but the function does nothing.

Comment: Hmm, have you checked the php.ini options regarding input and output treatment?

Also, have you checked the code that PRODUCES that url? I don't think you can resolve this on the decoding side, it's the encoding side that isn't working properly, in my modest opinion...